# Solving $w_{i}\frac{\frac{w_{j}}{w_{i}}x_{i}^{*}}{(1+\frac{w_{j}}{w_{i}})x_{i}^{*2}}=1$ for $x_i^{*}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the following equation for $x_{i}^{*}$?

$$w_{i}\frac{\frac{w_{j}}{w_{i}}x_{i}^{*}}{(1+\frac{w_{j}}{w_{i}})x_{i}^{*2}}=1$$

Correct solution is given as:

$$x_{i}^{*}=\frac{w_{i}^{2}w_{j}}{(w_{i}+w_{j})^2}$$

My answer is the above but without the squares. I calculated this by simply cancelling the exponent in the denominator and solving for x, but my answer does not have squares in it.

---

Here's the source:

[image]

Comment: You mean $x_i^{\ast}$? Note that you can remove the one in the numerator and reduce the exponent of the one in the denominator.

Comment: Yes I mean xi*. My answers are completely different from my professor's. He lists the correct solution as ((w_i)^2 . w_j)/(w_i + w_j)^2

Comment: @Jfischer My answer is the above but without squares

Comment: @Blue Done. I added the correct solution and my reasoning.

Comment: I do not see your reasoning.  Your solution (without the squares) is correct.  If the original problem had $(1+w_j/w_i)^2$ in the denominator, then the solution would be the one given as "correct".

Comment: @GEdgar My reasoning is that I simply cancelled the exponent on the x-term in the denominator (and removed the x in the numerator). Then rearranged and solved for x (as usual). But the solution given by my professor is the one listed with the squares in it. So are you saying the 'solution' he gave is incorrect?

Comment: One is incorrect: the solution he gave, or the problem you gave.

Comment: @Jfischer Hi, I couldn't link images, so please take a quick look here to see the full solution (where X=x_i+x_j). https://imgur.com/a/MEzFzY5

Comment: @DGD_987: (I've added the image to the question for you.) ... I may be missing something, but it looks to me like, after the substitution, the *entire denominator* should have been squared; that is, $$w_{i}\frac{\frac{w_{j}}{w_{i}}x_{i}^{*}}{\left((1+\frac{w_{j}}{w_{i}})x_{i}^{*}\right)^2}=1$$ This would make the professor's solution correct.

Comment: @Blue Oh yes that's it... I can't believe such a small slip-up had me stumped on such a simple question. Anyway, I've solved it, thanks.